# Unable to convert hex code to unicode characters, get unicodeescape error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, unicode

I have a pandas dataframe with **hex values** as given below:

```
df['col1']

<0020>
<0938>
<002E>
<092B>
<092B>
<0916>
<0915>
<0915>
<096F>
<096C>
```

I want to convert the `hex values` to their corresponding unicode literals. So, I try to do the following:

`df['col1'] = df['col1'].apply(lambda x : '\u' + str(x)[1:-1])`

Hoping, that this would convert it to my *required unicode literal*, but I get the following error:

```
File "<ipython-input-22-891ccdd39e79>", line 1
    df['col1'].apply(lambda x : '\u' +  str(x)[1:-1])
                                      ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: truncated \uXXXX escape
```

In python3, when we try the following we get :

```
>>> string1 = '\u03b4'
>>> print(string1)
>>> δ
```

So, I tried adding **\u** to my given string, I also tried adding `\\u`, but that shows up as ***two backslashes*** . Also, adding a `r` before `\u`, also ends up showing two backslashes, instead of the unicode literal. I also tried `decode-unicode`, but it didn't work either.

Also, it'd be great, if someone can explain the concept of **rawstrings** , **\u**, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oops, literals are for... literal values! As soon as you have variables, you should use conversion functions like `int` and `chr`.

Here you have a column containing strings. For each cell in the column, you want to remove first and last character, process what remains as an hex value, and get the unicode character with that code point. In Python, it just reads:

```
df['col1'].apply(lambda x: chr(int(x[1:-1], 16)))
```

And with your values, it gives:

```
0     
1    स
2    .
3    फ
4    फ
5    ख
6    क
7    क
8    ९
9    ६
```

---

Now for the reason of your error.

`\uxxxx` escape sequences are intended for the Python *parser*. When they are found in a string literal they are automatically replaced with the unicode character having that code point. You can use the `codecs` module and the `unicode_escape` encoding to decode a string that would contain *actual* `\u` character characters (meaning that you escape the backslash as in `"\\uxxx"`, but as you have directly an hex representation of the code point, it is simpler to directly use the `chr` function.

And in your initial code, when you write `'\u'`, the parser sees the initial part of an encoded character and tries to decode it immediately... but cannot find the hexa code point after it, so it throws the exception. If you really want to go that way, you have to double the backslash (`\`) to escape it and store it *as is* in the string and then use `codecs.decode(..., encoding='unicode_escape')` to decode the string as shown in [@ndclt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57944690/3545273). But I do not advise you to do so.

References are to be found in the Standard Python Library documentation, `chr` function and `codecs` module.

Comment: Can you explain more in depth, or give some links, where I can read up on this topic. `chr` definitely solves my problem, but I'd also like to learn why I got that `unicode error`.

Answer (score 1):

In order to convert all your codes into unicode here one line:

```py
import codecs
import pandas as pd
(
    # create a series with the prefix  "\u" to add to the existing column
    pd.Series([r'\u'] * len(df['col1']))
    # str.strip deletes the "<" and ">" from your column
    # str.cat concatenates the prefix created before to the existing column
    .str.cat(df['col1'].str.strip('<>'))
    # then you apply a conversion from the raw string to normal string.
    .apply(codecs.decode, args=['unicode_escape'])
)
```

In the previous code, you have to create the prefix as a raw string. If not, Python is waiting for a valid utf-8 code (the error you have in your code).

*Edit*: I add the explanation from [Serge Ballesta post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57945005)

> \uxxxx escape sequences are intended for the Python parser. When they are found in a string literal they are automatically replaced with the unicode character having that code point. You can use the codecs module and the unicode_escape encoding to decode a string that would contain actual \u character characters (meaning that you escape the backslash as in "\uxxx", but as you have directly an hex representation of the code point, it is simpler to directly use the chr function.

His solution is more elegant than mine.

Comment: _In the previous code, you have to create the prefix as a raw string._  @ndclt Can you please explain more, on this.